# How to add a terminfo entry systemwide?

Tags: terminal, bash

I would like to add terminfo entries systemwide for `rxvt-unicode` and `rxvt-unicode-256color`. However, when I try to run:

```
HOST:terms alexreinking$ ls   
rxvt-unicode        rxvt-unicode-256color
HOST:terms alexreinking$ sudo cp rxvt-unicode* /usr/share/terminfo/72/
cp: /usr/share/terminfo/72/rxvt-unicode: Operation not permitted
cp: /usr/share/terminfo/72/rxvt-unicode-256color: Operation not permitted
```

I get "Operation not permitted" even with sudo. I am aware this might have to do with macOS's system integrity protection. Must I go through the process of disabling it, copying the files, and then re-enabling it just to do this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: it's not what you asked for but why not use the local user folder? `$HOME/.terminfo/`

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is to create a directory `~/.terminfo/72` and put the files there.

Comment: Is there some way to make this default in every new user's home directory? The point of the question is to add the terminfo _systemwide_